# Como não gravar dados duplicados no MySQL com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou aprendendo PHP e, para começar, estou fazendo um projeto de agenda telefônica, com nome, DDD e telefone.

No entanto, antes dos novos dados ser inserido, como faço para conferir se o mesmo número de telefone já está cadastrado?

Comment: Preferi não responder pois essa lógica fere uma lógica básica desse tipo de negócio. Uma pessoa pode mudar de endereço, e outra ocupar o local e geralmente terá o número de telefone transferido para seu nome. O dono original terá outro número em outro local.. A coisa complica ainda mais se for números móveis pois nem precisa mudar de endereço.. Pessoas trocam de celular constantemente.. vc pode até verificar se o número já existe, porém, impedir um cadastro com base nesse critério acaba engessando o modelo de negócio.

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer isso basta verificar se o dado que se pretende inserir já existe no banco de dados ou não, eis um exemplo básico.

```
<?php
if(!$conect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tabela_')) die ('erro ao conectar');
#Recolhendo os dados do formulário
$dado1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['dado1']);
$dado2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['dado2']);
# Verificando apenas um campo, no caso dado1.
$sql = $conect->query("SELECT * FROM tabela_ WHERE dado1='$dado1'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "Este usuário já existe";
exit();
} else {
 if(!$conect->query("INSERT INTO tabela_ (dado1,dado2) VALUES ('$dado1','$dado2')")) die ('Os dados não foram inseridos');
 echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
}
```

Nesse exemplo se o valor do campo dado1 do formulário já existir nessa linha da tabela ele não é novamente adicionado.

Isso também pode ser resolvido ao criar a tabela.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela_(
  dado1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY(dado1) # Aqui especificamos que a linha dado1 será única, e não poderá ter outra de igual valor nessa mesma tabela.
 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Existe também uma maneira de se executar diretamente uma query no MYSQL que só inserirá o registro caso o mesmo não exista. É um **Insert Condicional**.

Exemplo:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(login, senha) 
    SELECT '$login_que_nao_pode_duplicar', 123456 
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$valor_que_nao_pode_duplicar')";
```

No caso, os valores do primeiro SELECT são os valores que vão ser inseridos.
Já o valor do segundo SELECT é o valor que é verificado se já existe.

Essa query, quando executada, retornará `UMA` linha afetada caso o valor passado no segundo SELECT (que tem que ser o mesmo do primeiro SELECT) não exista ainda na sua tabela.

Tanto é que, se você executá-la novamente essa mesma query, retornará `ZERO` linhas afetadas.

Outro exemplo com PDO:

```
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

   $nome = 'Wallace';
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(login, senha) SELECT '$nome', '123456' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$nome')");
   $stmt->execute();

   print_r($stmt->rowCount());
```

Quando abro a página, o **print_r** exibe "1". Quando atualizo a página, ele exibe "0".
Ao trocar o nome da variável $nome, você obteria $1 novamente.
Isso significa que a query só inseriu o registro quando eles não existiam. :)

Assim, você poderá fazer a execução dessa query tranquilamente; e, caso retorne "0", você poderá exibir uma mensagem de alerta para o usuário, por exemplo.

Comment: Não é mais simples capturar a exception de duplicate constraint então ?

Comment: Quando o sistema é todo orientadinho a objeto, sim, @gmsantos

Comment: Mesmo utilizando `mysql_*` é possível capturar exceptions e usar a constraint do banco de dados, o paradigma não influencia.

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode colocar o campo que você não quer repetição como `UNIQUE`:

```
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `campo_da_tabela_UNIQUE`
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma `CONSTRAINT`.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT cunique_table_customer_primary UNIQUE (column1, column2)
```