# Dupla inserção com mssql_query

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tendo um pequeno problema e gostaria de ajuda para resolvê-lo. Tenho um código que faz a inserção num banco de dados SQL SERVER através do php. Está tudo direitinho, exceto que dois "INSERT" no banco estão sendo feitos. Não consigo ver o que está errado, por isso gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar

A variável $envio é acionada assim que o formulário é enviado. Não sei mesmo o porquê desse duplo INSERT :(

```
if($envio){

$pastaupload = 'candidatos/';
$arquivoupload = $pastaupload .  time() . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];   

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $arquivoupload );
$caminho = "http://meusite.com.br/".$arquivoupload;

$insert ="INSERT INTO CANDIDATO (NOME, DH_NASCIMENTO, CEP, ENDERECO, NUMERO, BAIRRO, MUNICIPIO, UF, TELEFONE, CELULAR, EMAIL, CD_SEGMENTO_CARGO, OBSERVACAO, PATH_CURRICULO, CD_STATUS, CD_USUARIO) VALUES ('$nome', '$datanascimento', '$cep', '$endereco', '$numero', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$uf', '$telefone', '$celular', '$email', $segmento, '$observacoes', '$caminho', 1, 12 )";

mssql_query($insert);

mssql_close($connection); 

}
```

Comment: Click duplo no submit? Pode usar o email como unique key para evitar registros duplicados.

Comment: Esta pergunta já tem resposta algures, deixa-me procurar o link.

Comment: O único problema foi o usuário não ter escolhido uma resposta, daí não ter conseguido marcar como repetida/relacionadas - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10744/como-n%C3%A3o-gravar-dados-duplicados-no-mysql-com-php/10745#10745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique que o form não está sendo submetido duas vezes. Um bom meio de fazer isso é tirar o `mssql_query` e simplesmente fazer um `echo "Test";` ou algo aparecido.

Se não dá, tenta também usar os `Developer Tools`, disponível em vários browsers. Normalamente há um meio de ver os submissões feitos.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o que estava acontecendo, eu estava usando uma função para subir os arquivos, a `move_uploaded_file()`.

Era ela que estava fazendo com que o registro fosse inserido duas vezes. Apenas coloquei ela dentro de um if e funcionou!

Testei o que vocês me sugestionaram, muito obrigado pela atenção de todos!