# Chamar função php através de um formulário

Tags: php, funções, post

Boa tarde,
estou tentando criar uma pagina no meu site é wordpress na qual o usuário escolhe um arquivo e esse arquivo atualiza uma tabela no banco de dados.

Cheguei código abaixo, mas quando clico em carregar dados, nada acontece.
A função não está sendo chamada.

```
<div style="width: 50%;margin: 20px auto; ">
   <form action="" method="POST">
    Selecione o arquivo desejado:
    <select>
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
      <?php 
         foreach(glob('files/*') as 
           $filename){
           $filename = basename($filename);
           echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
         }
      ?>
    </select> 
   <input type='submit' value='Carregar dados'>
</form>
</div>

<?php

if(isset($_POST)){         
 function insere() {
    echo $filename;
    echo "apagando dados da tabela...<br>"; 
    $delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `i_renda`");

    $ler=file("files/".$filename);

    foreach($ler as $linha) {
        $dados=explode(';',$linha); 
        list($nome, $cpf, $nascimento, $valor, $ano_vigencia)=$dados; 

        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO i_renda (nome, cpf, nascimento, valor, ano_vigencia) VALUES ('".utf8_encode($nome)."', '$cpf', '$nascimento', '$valor', '$ano_vigencia')"  );
    } 
    echo "Dados incluidos com sucesso!"; exit;
    }       
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: voce quer inserir o que foi selecionado nesta página em outro página ? ou somente que ele se comunique com outra página no momento que der submit ?

Comment: Você não está chamando ela em momento algum nessa pagina que mandou, ali você só criou, chame após a criação

Comment: Victor, a minha ideia é que tudo acontecesse na mesma pagina. O usuário seleciona o arquivo e clica pra carregar no banco de dados. Nesse caso, a função do form é somente selecionar o arquivo e passar esse parâmetro pra função PHP que vai inserir os dados no banco.

Comment: arllondias, é verdade. Adicionei a chamada da função dentro do if. Mas ocorreu outro erro. Ele tá executando a função quando carrega a página, antes do usuário escolher o arquivo e clicar no botão.

Comment: Esse seu `if(isset($_POST)){` funciona? aqui comigo não funciona, ou seja, entra no if sem submeter o formulário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  function insere() {
     ...........
     ...........
  }

 //ao submeter o formulário chame a função
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    insere();      
 }
```

> Coloque um name no botão submit

`<input type='submit' name="submit" value='Carregar dados'>`

**Não bastaria usar somente a condição if para executar o código?**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $filename;
    echo "apagando dados da tabela...<br>"; 
    $delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `i_renda`");

    $ler=file("files/".$filename);

    foreach($ler as $linha) {
        $dados=explode(';',$linha); 
        list($nome, $cpf, $nascimento, $valor, $ano_vigencia)=$dados; 

        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO i_renda (nome, cpf, nascimento, valor, ano_vigencia) VALUES ('".utf8_encode($nome)."', '$cpf', '$nascimento', '$valor', '$ano_vigencia')"  );
    } 
    echo "Dados incluidos com sucesso!"; 
    exit;     
}
?>
```

> De acordo com o comentário `"se eu der f5, ele passa direito e executa direto a função"`, temos que, por exemplo no Google, ao dar refresh na página, surge a caixa de dialogo `A página que você está procurando usou as informações inseridas. Voltar à essa página poderá fazer com que todas as ações realizadas antes sejam repetidas. Deseja continuar?` daí se clicar em `cancelar` não haverá novo insert, entretanto, para evitar inserção de dados repetidos no banco de dados, veja como fazer nesse post [**Como não gravar dados duplicados no MySQL com PHP**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10744/como-n%C3%A3o-gravar-dados-duplicados-no-mysql-com-php)

Comment: Oi Leo, funcionou. Mas só funciona na primeira vez q eu carrego a pagina, se eu der f5, ele passa direito e executa direto a função. Como se uma vez clicado no submit, ficasse sempre ativo.

Comment: @NathaliaNegrão, `"se der f5,, temos que, por exemplo no Google, surge a caixa de dialogo `A página que você está procurando usou as informações inseridas. Voltar à essa página poderá fazer com que todas as ações realizadas antes sejam repetidas. Deseja continuar?` daí se clicar em `cancelar` não haverá novo insert, entretanto, para evitar inserção de dados repetidos no banco de dados, veja como nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10744/como-n%C3%A3o-gravar-dados-duplicados-no-mysql-com-php

Comment: achei uma solução nessa question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690541/best-way-to-avoid-the-submit-due-to-a-refresh-of-the-page
Ao inves de colocar no `echo` no final, coloquei um `header('Location: ../enviado');`

Answer (score 0):

Solução final:

```
<div style="width: 50%;margin: 20px auto; ">

 <form action="" method="POST">
  Selecione o arquivo desejado:
  <select name="file">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
    <?php 
       foreach(glob('files/*') as $filename){
         $filename = basename($filename);
         echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
       }
    ?>
  </select> 
  <input type='submit' value='Carregar dados' name='submit'>
 </form>
</div>

<?php  
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
   $filename = $_POST['file'];
   $delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `i_renda`");
   $ler=file("files/".$filename);
   foreach($ler as $linha) {
    $dados=explode(';',$linha); 
    list($nome, $cpf, $nascimento, $valor, $ano_vigencia)=$dados; 
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO i_renda (nome, cpf, nascimento, valor, ano_vigencia) VALUES ('".utf8_encode($nome)."', '$cpf', '$nascimento', '$valor', '$ano_vigencia')"  );
   }
   header('Location: ../enviado');
   exit;            
 }
?>
```