# Dados duplicados ao enviar formulario e F5 e também armazena valores vazios

Tags: php, mysql

Sempre que aperto f5 ou clico em enviar, o php armazena os dados novamente. Sei que é um problema comum e já tentei redirecionar com o header, mas ele esta incluso no index.php com include.

Sei também que as palavras msql devem ter um i no final mas vou adaptar depois, utilizei php e ajax como faço para resolver o problema?

Segue codigo abaixo:

**O index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AjaxTeste.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<section>
    <form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario">
        <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="nome" name="nome"><br>
        <input type="text" id="sobrenome" placeholder="sobrenome" 
name="sobrenome"><br>
        <input type="email" id="email"  placeholder="e-mail" name="email"> 
<br>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" 
name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar" id="enviar" 
name="enviar"><br>
        </form>
    <div id="dados"><p></p></div>
```

```
</section>

<footer>
</footer>
<?php 
include "cadastro/dados.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**O jquery/Ajax**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enviar").click(function(){
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        var sobrenome = $("#sobrenome").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var senha = $("#password").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cadastro/dados.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data:{

            "nome": nome,
            "sobrenome": sobrenome,
            "email": email,
            "senha": senha
        }

        sucess:function(data){
            $("#dados" :p).html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
});
```

**O dados.php**

```
<?php  
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die("não foi possivel 
ligar ao servidor");
$db = mysql_select_db("usuario", $connect) or die ("impossivel entrar no 
banco de dados");


if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['password'];
if (empty($nome)||strlen($nome)<1){
    echo "Prencha o(s) campo(s)";


if (empty($sobrenome) ||strlen($sobrenome)<1){
    echo "Prencha o(s) campo(s)";

if(empty($email) ||strlen($email)<1){
    echo "Prencha o(s) campo(s)";

 if(empty($senha)|| strlen($senha)<1 ){
echo "Prencha o(s) campo(s)";


}}


    $query = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome,sobrenome,email,senha) VALUES 
   ('$nome','$sobrenome','$email','$senha')";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $buscar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY id DESC") or 
   die(mysql_error());
    $consulta= mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($buscar);



if ($rows>0) {


while ($consulta= mysql_fetch_array($buscar)){  

    echo "Seu nome é "." ".$consulta['nome']. " ".$consulta['sobrenome']. " 
     ". 
    "com o email ". $consulta['email']."<br>";}
}
   //if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    //  header("location: redireciona.php");

}
}

}
?>
```

Comment: veja esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10744/como-n%C3%A3o-gravar-dados-duplicados-no-mysql-com-php

Answer (score 2):

Olá,
1º - O script está feito para gravar toda vez q "enviar" for clicado. Uma opção seria desativar o botão enviar após o click. Ex: `$("#enviar").prop("disabled",true);`

2º - Toda a parte da query está dentro dos if's do nome e sobrenome. Usando um programa ou site que faça indentação automática fica fácil ver. Ex: [PHPFormatter](http://www.phpformatter.com/), [PHPBeautifier](http://phpbeautifier.com/)

Inserir direto do $_POST não é seguro

Exemplo do código para dados.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("não foi possivel ligar ao servidor");
$db = mysql_select_db("usuario", $connect) or die("impossivel entrar no banco de dados");


if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'enviar'))) {

    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome');
    $sobrenome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sobrenome');
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
    if (empty($nome)) {
        die("Prencha o(s) campo(s) de nome");
    }

    if (empty($sobrenome)) {
        die("Prencha o campo sobrenome");
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        die("Prencha o campo de email");
    }
    if (empty($senha)) {
        die("Prencha o campo de senha");
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `cadastro` (`nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$sobrenome}','{$email}','{$senha}')";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $buscar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cadastro` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    $consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($buscar);

    if ($rows > 0) {
        while ($consulta = mysql_fetch_array($buscar)) {
            echo "Seu nome é {$consulta['nome']} {$consulta['sobrenome']} com o email {$consulta['email']} <br>";
        }
    }
    //if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    //  header("location: redireciona.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar aqui